# Adding [0] causes callback to be called twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing utility for some minecraft stuff, whatever... So, first of all I have a code that can extract specified files from archive and give there content in callback:

```
const unzip = require("unzip-stream");
const Volume = require("memfs").Volume;
const mfs = new Volume();
const fs = require("fs");

function getFile(archive, path, cb) {
    let called = false;

    fs.createReadStream(archive)
        .pipe(unzip.Parse())
        .on("entry", function(entity) {
            if (path.includes(entity.path)) {
                entity.pipe(mfs.createWriteStream("/" + path))
                    .on("close", function() {
                        mfs.readFile("/" + path, function(err, content) {
                            if (!called) cb(content);
                            called = true;
                            mfs.reset();
                        });
                    }).on("err", () => {});
            } else {
                entity.autodrain();
            }
        });
}

module.exports = { getFile };
```

It works perfect when I test it in interactive console:

```
require("./zip").getFile("minecraft-mod.jar", ["mcmod.info", "cccmod.info"], console.log); // <= Works fine! Calls callback ONCE!
```

When I started to develop utility using this code I discovered a VERY strange thing.

So I have filenames in `files` array.

I'm using `async/eachSeries` to iterate over it. I have no callback function - only iterate one.

I have this code to parse .json files in mods:

```
let modinfo = Object.create(JSON.parse(content.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")));
```

It also works fine. But here comes magic...

So, .json files can contain *array* or *object*. If it's *array* we need to take first element of it:

```
if (modinfo[0]) modinfo = modinfo[0];
```

It works.

But, if it's object we need to take first element of `modlist` property in in:

```
else modinfo = modinfo.modlist[0];
```

And if modinfo was and object boom - callback now fires TWICE! WHAT?

But, if I remove [0] from else condition:

```
else modinfo = moninfo.modlist; // <= No [0]
```

Callback will be called ONCE! ???

[image]

[image]

If I try to do something like this:

```
if (modinfo[0]) modinfo = modinfo[0];
else {
    const x = modinfo.modlist;
    modinfo = x[0];
}
```

Same thing happens...

Also, it's called without arguments.

I tried to investigate - where callback is called twice. Read the zip extractor code again... It has those lines:

This:

```
let called = false;
```

And those:

```
if (!called) cb(content);
called = true;
```

So, if for some reason even this condition fires up two times:

```
if (path.includes(entity.path)) {
```

It should not call callback, right? No! Not only that, but if I try to

```
console.log(called);
```

It will log `false` two times!

NodeJS version: v8.0.0

Full code:

```js
function startSignCheck() {
  clear();

  const files = fs.readdirSync("../mods");

  async.eachSeries(files, function(file, cb) {
    console.log("[>]", file);

    zip.getFile("../mods/" + file, ["mcmod.info", "cccmod.info"], function(content) {
      console.log(content);
      console.log(Buffer.isBuffer(content));

      if (content != undefined) content = content.toString();

      if (!content) return cb();

      let modinfo = Object.create(JSON.parse(content.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")));

      if (modinfo[0]) modinfo = modinfo[0];
      else modinfo = modinfo.modlist[0];

      //if (!modinfo.name) return cb();

      /*curse.searchMod(modinfo.name, modinfo.version, curse.versions[modinfo.mcversion], function(link) {
       if (!link) return cb();

       signature.generateMD5("../mods/" + file, function(localSignature) {
        signature.URLgenerateMD5(link, function(curseSignature) {
         if (localSignature === curseSignature) {
          console.log(file, "- Подпись верна".green);
         } else {
          console.log(file.bgWhite.red + " - Подпись неверна".bgWhite.red);
         }

         cb();
        });
       });
      });*/
    });
  });
}
```

Example contents of `mcmod.info` is:

```
{
  "modListVersion": 2,
  "modList": [{
    "modid": "journeymap",
    "name": "JourneyMap",
    "description": "JourneyMap Unlimited Edition: Real-time map in-game or in a web browser as you explore.",
    "version": "1.7.10-5.1.4p2",
    "mcversion": "1.7.10",
    "url": "http://journeymap.info",
    "updateUrl": "",
    "authorList": ["techbrew", "mysticdrew"],
    "logoFile": "assets/journeymap/web/img/ico/journeymap144.png",
    "screenshots": [],
    "dependants":[],
    "dependencies": ["Forge@[10.13.4.1558,)"],
    "requiredMods": ["Forge@[10.13.4.1558,)"],
    "useDependencyInformation": true
  }]
}
```

Comment: Although I appreciate your very thorough question, could you put your annotated code in as it is, in a big block please? Easier to read

Comment: @MattFletcher https://pastebin.com/XdMLZ0rd

Comment: All the code that uses `modinfo` is commented out. What callback are you talking about?

Comment: @Barmar one for `zip.getFile`

Comment: @Barmar once again: if you change `modinfo.modlist[0]` to `modinfo.modlist` or simply remove it callback for `zip.getFile` will be called ones. If you leave `modinfo.modlist[0]` callback for `zip.getFile` will be called twice, first time with file content, second - without.

Comment: @Barmar Here's the exact jar file that I extract: https://files.fm/u/8nmmggcc .

Comment: Why are you using `Object.create()` instead of just `modinfo = JSON.parse(content)`?

Comment: `modlist` should be `modList`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried to add it to see what happens. If you remove `Object.create()` nothing changes.

Comment: @Barmar oh, yeah! I didn't noticed that.

Comment: @Barmar works fine now, thanks

Comment: Weird, I wonder why that fixes it.

Comment: You should be getting an error saying that you can't access `[0]` of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was using `modlist` instead of `modList`. Not it works! Thanks for solution, [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

Comment: Aaaaah haha, classic :D